# How to add part of an external file in HTML file programatically?

Tags: html

the content of a body of a table is generated by a java code and exports it in a file. How do i read that programatically in the table definition in the html file ?

Java Program Generates the below code

```
            <tr>
                <th>Filename</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>The Hitch Hiker's Guide to the Galaxy</td>
                <td>Book</td>
                <td>28/01/2011</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>The Hitch Hiker's Guide to the Galaxy</td>
                <td>Film</td>
                <td>28/01/2011</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dirk Gently's Holistic Detective Agency</td>
                <td>TV Series</td>
                <td>28/01/2011</td>
            </tr>
```

.

```
<div id="liveFilter">
    <div class="liveFilterContainer">
        <input type="text" class="liveFilterInput default" value="Live Filter" />
        <a href="#" class="clearField" title="Clear Filter">x</a>
    </div>
    <div class="noResults"><strong>Sorry.</strong> There is no match for your filter; please try again.</div>
    <table class="liveFilterList" border="0">
        <tbody>


 <!-- Java Genrated code goes here-->

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **jsp:include** to include HTML code into java file,

```
<jsp:include page="table.html" flush="true" />
```

include file has to be specified as a **"relative path"**.

The relative URL looks like a **pathname**. It can't contain a protocol name, port number, or domain name. The URL can be absolute or relative to the current JSP page. If it is absolute (beginning with a /), the pathname is resolved by your web or application server. 
you could NOT do the following:

```
 <jsp:include page="http://www.cnn.com/todayNews.html">
```

---

***Updated***
You can use jquery ajax to include **table.html** page,

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('#btnload').click(function () { 
        $.ajax({
            context: this,
            dataType : "html",
            url : "table.html",
            success : function(results) {
                $(this).html(results);
            }
        });
    }); 
</script> 
</head>
<body>
    <button name="btnload" id="btnload" value="load code" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JSP is not an option because my file is a HTML file and i am not allowed to use JSP.

Comment: you have both file html?

Comment: Well i had one in txt and one in HTML but i can have both in HTML that can be done easily

Comment: you should use ajax jquery method to load other html file.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is iframes (thanks to user1153551 - AJAX is also good but requires additional programming).

Another option is to generate the entire presentation HTML based on the stored data and a template.

Comment: but I actually use jQuery also to filter the search that would be an issue right ?

Comment: Correct. Then you can use AJAX to load the data (you can even format them as JSON for the ease of handling) and build the DOM dynamically.